# Python: filter objects in a list which has unique id values

Tags: python, list, filtering

I have a list of objects in Python, like:

```
my_list = [
    SomeObject(id="hello", name="world"),
    SomeObject(id="hello", name="world"),
    SomeObject(id="foo", name="bar"),
]
```

Now I want a new list which only contains the object which has unique `id` values, so the expected list will be:

```
expected_list = [
    SomeObject(id="hello", name="world"),
    SomeObject(id="foo", name="bar"),
]
```

Is there a method in Python which can perform such a list filtering?

---

Update:

What I finally do is, create two lists, `unique_id_list = []`, and `unique_object_list = []`. for-loop: If `object.id` not in `unique_id_list`, append the id into `unique_id_list`, item in `unique_object_list`. Otherwise do nothing. Please also refer to the "most correct way" to do it properly (the voted answer).

Comment: No, but it's trivial to write one.

Comment: regarding your _Update:_ - you might benefit from using `set` instead of `list` due to `O(1)` lookup instead of `O(n)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the cleanest way is, if you are able to define the `SomeObject` class yourself, by defining what makes `SomeObject` unique and specify the `__eq__`, `__ne__` and `__hash__` methods that allow for uniqueness comparison. `__str__` is just added so that we can print it with values instead of printing e.g. `<__main__.SomeObject object at 0x10b2dedf0>`

```
class SomeObject:

    def __init__(self, id, name):
        self.id = id
        self.name = name

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return isinstance(other, self.__class__) and self.id == other.id

    def __ne__(self, other):
        return not self == other

    def __hash__(self):
        return hash(self.id)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return "<SomeObject id={} name={}>".format(self.id, self.name)
```

then you can apply `set`, thus filtering out the duplicate objects, and convert it back to a list:

```
my_list = [
    SomeObject(id="hello", name="world"),
    SomeObject(id="hello", name="world"),
    SomeObject(id="foo", name="bar"),
]

filtered = list(set(my_list))

# print all objects in the list:
[print(o) for o in filtered]
```

will print out the items of your filtered list:

```
<SomeObject id=hello name=world>
<SomeObject id=foo name=bar>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the ids to a set, then delete the list members that are not unique:

```
def some_object(id="bar", name="baz"):
    return id, name


my_list = [
    some_object(id="hello", name="world"),
    some_object(id="hello", name="world"),
    some_object(id="foo", name="bar"),
]

print(my_list)
ids = set()
for obj in my_list:
    if (id := obj[0]) in ids:
        del my_list[my_list.index(obj)]
    ids.add(obj[0])

print(my_list)
```

Returning:

```
[('hello', 'world'), ('hello', 'world'), ('foo', 'bar')]
[('hello', 'world'), ('foo', 'bar')]
```

Comment: That doesn't exactly work though; the person who asked only wanted unique id values and this method filters for unique names as well.

Answer (score 0):

Loop through each element in my_list, checking against all elements in expected_list: If any of them match ids, don't add it to the list.

```py
def delete_duplicates(total_list):
    expected_list = []
    in_expected_list = False
    for i in total_list:
        for j in expected_list:
            if j.id == i.id:
                in_expected_list = True
        if not in_expected_list:
            expected_list.append(i)
        in_expected_list = False

    return expected_list
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer. 2-level for-loop is a bit too much. What I finally do is, create two lists, unique_id_list = [], and unique_object_list = []. for-loop: If object.id not in unique_id_list, append the id into unique_id_list, item in unique_object_list. Otherwise do nothing.

Comment: Not a problem at all!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `itertools.groupby` as in:

```
class SomeObject:
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.__dict__.update(kwargs)


my_list = [
    SomeObject(id="hello", name="world"),
    SomeObject(id="foo", name="bar"),
    SomeObject(id="hello", name="world")
]

from itertools import groupby

sort_function = lambda obj: obj.id
my_list = [list(item)[0] 
           for key, item in groupby(sorted(my_list, key=sort_function), key=sort_function)]
print(my_list)
```